# How to convert a string date to date format?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
Thu Apr 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
```

I tried:

```
dateStart = new Date(dateStart);
```

But that's not the right

I'm looking at `23/4/20`

Comment: now you can manipulate the output, like `var dateAsString = ${dateStart.getDate()}/${dateStart.getMonth()+1}/${dateStart.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)}` no?

Comment: @balexandre let me try it, because I was about to use moment but I didn't want a new library

Comment: @balexandre that piece is broken tho

Comment:  NOOooooo, please don't use MomentJs... [you can do so many things without it](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs)!

Comment: @balexandre exactly ahhaha could you paste your bit into an answer pls

Comment: "that piece is broken tho" not really, the comment editor is just not powerful enough to have the "`" -> https://i.imgur.com/ePv6Y7Y.png 

Comment: @balexandre put it into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if, when you think about manipulating `Date` object you think about MomentJs ... don't rush! [you might not even need](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs) it's [66Kb](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=moment) for a very simple thing!

in your case, it's quite simple:

as you have already a `date()` object, [reading the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you have access to all parts of the date, though `getMonth()` get's a bit weird ‍♂️

so:

```js
var dateStart = new Date()
var dateAsString = `${dateStart.getDate()}/${dateStart.getMonth()+1}/${dateStart.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)}`

console.log(dateAsString)
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Comment: He didn't `` his string template, which is the same answer as mine. You need to check your date init

Comment: missing the "`" ... the editor does not like me today 

Comment: why didn't you got my comment working? it's copy/paste of what I commented before buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```js
const dateStart = new Date('Thu Apr 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200');
const formatted = `${dateStart.getDate()}/${dateStart.getMonth() + 1}/${dateStart.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)}`
```

Comment: (index):869 Uncaught TypeError: dateStart.getDate is not a function

Comment: You got a problem initializing your date variable. Copy/paste it in the console and it should work

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-dqnph?file=/index.js 
It's working

Comment: `dateStart = new Date(dateStart);
                dateEnd = new Date(dateEnd);
                dateStart = `${dateStart.getDate()}/${dateStart.getMonth() + 1}/${dateStart.getFullYear().toString().slice(2)}`;
                dateEnd = `${dateStart.getDate()}/${dateStart.getMonth() + 1}/${dateStart.getFullYear().toString().slice(2)}`;`

Answer (score 0):

In Nodejs. [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat). [Snippet](https://repl.it/@MHamzaRajput/RawBurlySyntax)

```
const DATE_FORMATER = require( 'dateformat' );
let datetime = DATE_FORMATER( new Date(dateStart), "dd/mm/yy" );
console.log(datetime);
```

Comment: that's not doing this is it? 23/4/20

Comment: let me add a snippet.

Comment: where would place dateStart?

Comment: I have added a snippet. You can test there.

Comment: In date constructor.